# Ubuntu 22.04 improve RDP connection and lag time

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, remote, rdp

I have an old desktop PC on which I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and I want to remote desktop it.

This is my `lsb_release -a` output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I have [Realvnc Server](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/) installed on it and works so-and-so, I get quite a lag sometimes. I also did the recommendations they have mentioned but not seeing a big improvement in lag time.

I've tried RDP from Ubuntu Settings > Sharing > RDP and was able to connect to it, but it is still laggy.

My monitor is always connected to it and open, I am fine with that. It is using a Display Port; I've tried with HDMI as well but did not see any noticeable difference in lag time.

I tried `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and seems I am on Gnome based on the output:

```
ubuntu:GNOME
```

My `sudo lshw -short` command output is:

```
H/W path               Device           Class          Description
==================================================================
                                        system         OptiPlex 9020 (05A4)
/0                                      bus            00V62H
/0/0                                    memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/3a                                   processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790
/0/3a/3b                                memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/3a/3c                                memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/3a/3d                                memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/3e                                   memory         8GiB System Memory
/0/3e/0                                 memory         DIMMProject-Id-Version: l
/0/3e/1                                 memory         8GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronou
/0/3e/2                                 memory         DIMMProject-Id-Version: l
/0/3e/3                                 memory         DIMMProject-Id-Version: l
/0/100                                  bridge         4th Gen Core Processor DR
/0/100/2               /dev/fb0         display        Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen C
/0/100/3               card0            multimedia     Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen C
/0/100/3/0             input10          input          HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pc
/0/100/3/1             input11          input          HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pc
/0/100/3/2             input8           input          HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pc
/0/100/3/3             input9           input          HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pc
/0/100/14                               bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chip
/0/100/14/0            usb3             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/9          input3           input          Logitech USB Keyboard Sys
/0/100/14/0/a                           input          Microsoft USB Optical Mou
/0/100/14/0/b                           generic        A6150
/0/100/14/1            usb4             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/6          scsi6            storage        PSSD T7
/0/100/14/1/6/0.0.0    /dev/sdb         disk           500GB PSSD T7
/0/100/14/1/6/0.0.0/1  /dev/sdb1        volume         465GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/16                               communication  8 Series/C220 Series Chip
/0/100/16.3                             communication  8 Series/C220 Series Chip
/0/100/19              eno1             network        Ethernet Connection I217-
/0/100/1a                               bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chip
/0/100/1a/1            usb1             bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a/1/1                           bus            Integrated Rate Matching 
/0/100/1b              card1            multimedia     8 Series/C220 Series Chip
/0/100/1b/0            input12          input          HDA Intel PCH Front Mic
/0/100/1b/1            input13          input          HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
/0/100/1b/2            input14          input          HDA Intel PCH Line Out
/0/100/1b/3            input15          input          HDA Intel PCH Front Headp
/0/100/1d                               bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chip
/0/100/1d/1            usb2             bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d/1/1                           bus            Integrated Rate Matching 
/0/100/1f                               bridge         Q87 Express LPC Controlle
/0/100/1f/0                             system         PnP device PNP0c01
/0/100/1f/1                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/2                             system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/100/1f/3                             generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/100/1f/4                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/5                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/6                             communication  PnP device PNP0501
/0/100/1f/7                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f.2            scsi1            storage        8 Series/C220 Series Chip
/0/100/1f.2/0          /dev/sda         disk           500GB ST500DM002-1SB10
/0/100/1f.2/0/1        /dev/sda1        volume         579MiB Windows NTFS volum
/0/100/1f.2/0/2        /dev/sda2        volume         465GiB Windows NTFS volum
/0/100/1f.2/1          /dev/cdrom       disk           DVD+-RW DS-8ABSH
/0/100/1f.2/1/0        /dev/cdrom       disk           
/0/100/1f.3                             bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chip
/1                     input0           input          Power Button
/2                     input1           input          Power Button
/3                     input2           input          Dell WMI hotkeys
/4                     input6           input          PixArt Microsoft USB Opti
/5                     input7           input          Video Bus
/6                     wlx0836c97f5b62  network        Wireless interface
```

I have tried Xorg before but seemed to be too slow, though happy to try again.

**If anyone has any suggestions on what I can use to Remote Desktop into it as it has low specs and not a great graphics card (i think it's an onboard one), that'd be amazing!**

Thank you!

PS: I understand that VNC is usually slower than RDP, I did try the regular RDP by default from Ubuntu but seems it is still slow; sometimes VNC seems faster than RDP. The RDP from Ubuntu has a lag as well a few seconds seeing my mouse being quite slow and delayed.

Comment: I you use freerdp, remmina from focal there are no lag.